# Bayesian parameter estimation using priors from MLE-parameters

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, fitting, gumbel-distribution

10 Points of maximum water levels available ONLY.
I am trying to fit the data to a gumbel/GEV distribution using the following method.

-MLE

-Bayesian

Problem
When i try to fit the data and get the distribution parameters using bayesian with no prior, the whole scheme goes unstable and no reasonable results are achieved.

Question
Is it reasonable to fit the data and estimate distribution parameters using MLE and then put these parameters as prior for Bayesian analysis.

Or it is kind of over fitting ?

what could be a better prior than uniform priors?

Regards

Comment: 1) Could you explain more specifically what you mean by a Bayesian analysis "with no prior"? This is a contradiction in terms. 2) How exactly do you intend to construct a prior (which is a distribution over parameters) from the MLE (which is a single point in parmeter space)?

Comment: 3) Using the MLE to construct a prior would be a form of fitting the prior to the data. This violates the conceptual meaning of a prior which, strictly speaking, should represent your beliefs before having seen the data. That said, there do exist (partially) Bayesian methods that use the data to fit hyperparameters controlling the prior. But, at first glance, your plan sounds like a more severe form of 'double dipping'.

Comment: thanks @user20160 for your inputs, for a GEV distribution I have to make such an input into my system --->type="GEV", method="Bayesian",initial=list(location=0, scale=0, shape=0) i would like correct my language, no prior means all parameters values at zero, which mean i have no idea of their values "no look at the data". in this case with 10 data points/values i am unable to find any thing using priors at zero. What could be a possible solution /prior for this case